# How do I access private instance variables in Obj-C or Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, instance-variables, access-modifiers

I'm trying to get access to `MKMapSnapshotter`'s private instance variables `_lodpiSnapshotCreator` and `_hidpiSnapshotCreator` in Swift on macOS.

Thanks to class-dump, I know they're there ([see here](https://github.com/onmyway133/Runtime-Headers/blob/master/macOS/10.13/MapKit.framework/MKMapSnapshotter.h)):

```
@interface MKMapSnapshotter : NSObject
{
    [...]
    VKMapSnapshotCreator *_lodpiSnapshotCreator;
    VKMapSnapshotCreator *_hidpiSnapshotCreator;
}
```

but no matter what I do, I can't get ahold of them.

This is how I checked whether I could access them or not:

```
let snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: snapshotOptions)

let varNames = ["_lodpiSnapshotCreator", "_hidpiSnapshotCreator"]
for varName in varNames {
    if let testIVar = class_getInstanceVariable(MKMapSnapshotter.self, varName) {
        if let test = object_getIvar(snapshotter, testIVar) as? VKMapSnapshotCreator {
            print(test)
        } else {
            print("Got ivar, but \(varName) is still nil (getInstanceVariable)")
        }
    } else {
        print("\(varName) is nil (getInstanceVariable)")
    }
}
```

Curiously, class_getInstanceVariable doesn't return nil, but object_getIvar does.

```
Got ivar, but _lodpiSnapshotCreator is still nil (getInstanceVariable)
Got ivar, but _hidpiSnapshotCreator is still nil (getInstanceVariable)
```

I'm at my wit's end here. All I can find via Google is people recommending the use of class_getInstanceVariable (which I already use) and key-value-coding (which doesn't work at all).

This must have been done before. Can anyone help me out?

**Edit**: So far, I have tried this:

```
@interface MKMapSnapshotter() {
    @public VKMapSnapshotCreator *_lodpiSnapshotCreator;
    @public VKMapSnapshotCreator *_hidpiSnapshotCreator;
}

@end
```

That compiles successfully, but when trying to use it, Swift keeps insisting that the members _lodpiSnapshotCreator and _hidpiSnapshotCreator don't exist.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do with those variables but it may be easier to just write an extension for the `MKMapSnapshotter` class

Comment: Go to MKMapSnaphotter and create getter and setter methods for the variables that you want to access.

Comment: @AgentSmith Trying to access my getter method results in [MKMapSnapshotter _hidpiSnapshotCreator]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: I guess a extension will not work either, I was going to write a test ext just to see everything, and I can't find mention of these `lodpiSnapshotCreator` or `hidpiSnapshotCreator`...it's kind of weird seeing dpi mentioned in iOS anyway I normally only see those in Android projects

Comment: @JacobBoyd This is for macOS. I probably should have said that in the question, whoops

Comment: @PeterW. my bad, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Since we don't have or control the source code we can't change the variables to properties. Just tried this works for your case:

```
extension MKMapSnapshotter {
   func getPrivateVariable() -> String? {
       return value(forKey: "_lodpiSnapshotCreator") as? String
   }

   open override func value(forUndefinedKey key: String) -> Any? {
       if key == "_lodpiSnapshotCreator" {
           return nil
       }
       return super.value(forUndefinedKey: key)
   }
}
```

You can find more about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1413457-value).

If this does not work then I believe that there is no way to access Objective-C instance variables from Swift. Only Objective-C properties get mapped to Swift properties.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: `getPrivateVariable()` just returns nil for me.

Comment: @PeterW. Forgot to mention that overriding value(forUndefinedKey:) is optional. value(forKey:) will crash if the private variable doesn't exist in the class unless you override value(forUndefinedKey:) and provide a default value.

Comment: I really only need that one property, so this will sadly not work for me. Thanks regardless!

Comment: Can you cast `VKMapSnapshotCreator *` to `String`?